# Access from template info of another blog (in the same network)

Tags: multisite, bloginfo, switch-to-blog

In my root blog (1), i have a custom post type that can be linked to an existing blog of my network. It does so by recording in post metas the ID of the blog it is linked to. I use `_blog_id` as a name for this data.

In a page of this root blog, i list these custom posts, and i easily retreive the meta i saved:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$blog_id = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '_blog_id', true);
```

Now, i have the ID of the blog i want information from, so i try the following:

```
switch_to_blog($blog_id);
$blog_url = get_bloginfo('url');
restore_current_blog();
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work because `$blog_url` has the URL of the root blog.

Worse: `switch_to_blog()` works but not `restore_current_blog()`, because subsequent calls to the LOOP functions now work in the sub-blog. For example, when calling `the_post_thumbnails()`, the image source is referred by "/uploads/sites/2/2014..." while i'm in the root site.

**As you could guess, i have two questions:**

1. **How to retreive blog info of another blog in the network, from the template of a blog?**
2. **Why does `switch_to_blog()`, followed by `restore_current_blog()` makes the LOOP functions to behave incorrectly?**

Thank you everyone! Have a great weekend!

Comment: Disable all plugins. Are you still seeing the issue with `switch_to_blog()` / `restore_current_blog()`? If not, re-enable your plugins one by one till the issue re-emerges. That'll tell you which plugin, if any, is at fault. If it's not a plugin, try using a default WP theme -- Twenty Thirteen or Twenty Fourteen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pat J: thank you for your answer. As an old developer as i am, that was one of the first reflex i had, i disabled plugins, and even custom functions. Nothing ever helped. I forgot to mention that out.

**But i found the solution**, and that's quite stupid, read that:

`$blog_id` is somehow used in the loop (or generally in the template) so you should never assign this variable. **`$blog_id` is a reserved variable in template!** Now i'll remember ;)

What happened is that, by changing `$blog_id`'s value, subsequent helper function calls were working on the wrong blog, thus using wrong upload folder for example.

It also addresses my first issue: `network_site_url($sub_blog_id)` gives me the URL of a foreign blog, as i needed. The `$blog_id` bug was affecting this behavior too.

Hope this helps!